# How to automatically open Bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a "About Us" page with 3 bootstrap accordion inside the page, let's just say "Stories", "Testimonials"

What I want to do is when I click the "FAQ" in the Navigation, it will go to "About Us" page and the "Testimonials" accordion is automatically expanded/opened.

**Menu Navigation:**

```
<a href="http://mydevwebsites.info/rmhc-WP/about-us" data-target="#collapseTwo" id="faqbtn">FAQ</a>
```

**About Us Page** (this is a sample page)

```
<a class="accordion-toggle accord-btn text-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> 
  <div class="accord-bg">
    Stories
    <span class="ico-holder"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
  </div>
</a>

<a class="accordion-toggle accord-btn text-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"> 
  <div class="accord-bg">
    Testimonials
    <span class="ico-holder"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: In jQuery use ('#idOfAboutUs').collapse('show')

Comment: @Sourabh-, the link is outside the about us page, so it will load first

Comment: When your about us page is loaded use the code that i gave.

Comment: While adding code blocks in question, please do format them properly by using either of these options (1) select the code block and click Ctrl + K or (2) select the code block and click on the `{}` icon in the tool bar. If this is not done, they get interpreted as normal HTML and will get rendered the same way how the code is rendered in your browser. The *using jQuery* part is generally not required in the title because the tags you add can help convey that information.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class "in" to your accordion that you would like open

View the accordion example here [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) (scroll down to tge accordion example)